# Launching Permissions of ios application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios10, iphone-privateapi, ios-permissions

Apple has documented ways to go to the settings app from any iOS app. But is there any way to launch the permissions (of the app) inside the settings app directly?

I saw this [private header (preferences framework)](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/PreferencesUI.framework) and it kind of seems to accomplish the task, but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, if I understood it right I have posted the right answer, if not kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, with [UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring):

```
if let appSettings = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appSettings)
}
```

Comment: Hi @arpit: This opens the settings application. from there it is one click away for viewing the permissions of your app. I want to jump there directly.

Comment: @Mj.B on iOS11, it does open what you want. And that's the best you will get: any deeper access to a specific sub-screen is strictly private and will get your app rejected during iTunes Connect review, unless new features are made available in future iOS/Xcode versions.